# Not using correctly javascript setTimeout / clearTimeout?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have problem with simple javascript and some ajax.

I have link that calls javascript function like this:

```
<div id="Button11" onmouseover="changeContent4()">Actions</div>
```

Javascript function that is called above is like this:

```
function changeContent4()
{
    BubbleOn()
    document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML='Some text here';
    clearTimeout(BOffi);
    var BOffi = setTimeout(BubbleOff, 20000);
}
```

This works, it runs BubbleOn function, places text to element text1, most likely it empties BOffi timeout and sets new timeout 20000ms for it.

Here is BubbleOn:

```
function BubbleOn() {
 $("#bubble").fadeIn(function() {
    })
}
```

And here is BubbleOff:

```
function BubbleOff() {
 $("#bubble").fadeOut(function() {
    })
}
```

As in functions BubbleOn and BubbleOff works. They just hide or show div named bubble which contains text1 element. When BOffi goes timeout it just runs the BubbleOff function. This works fine. The problem is that when BubbleOff has been run and mouse is placed immediately over link that runs changeContent4(), It does make the bubble div visible again and places text there again but then bubble div fades out inside a second! Not after 20000ms. After this if the mouse is placed again to run changeContent4() everything works great. If there is about millisecond longer time than a second between the bubble fadeout and placing the mouse over changeContent4() launcher it works and waits 20000ms. Less than a second and bubble is shown about second...

What can cause this? Could it be that fadeOut is still running even the bubble is vanished from the screen and therefore it does not reset the BOffi counter? Which could have 1 second or less time left and then runs BubbleOff again after that magical second?

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas to try:

1. put "clearTimeout(BOffi);" at the top of the function before "BubbleOn();".
2. declare BOffi as a global variable.

So:

```
var BOffi;
function changeContent4()
{
  clearTimeout(BOffi);
  BubbleOn();
  document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML='Some text here';
  BOffi = setTimeout(BubbleOff, 20000);
}
```

or you can use window.BOffi instead.

Comment: This seems to have fixed to problem! Thank you! :)

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but could you please explain a bit on the *why*?

Comment: Because in my version BOffi is vanished when timeout goes. Also it is better to clear global BOffi before using it again. As far as i understand... :)

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance I notice this var BOffi = setTimeout(BubbleOff, 20000);. This creates a local variable. After the function is executed, is lost. Second time function is called Boffi is some random residual value.

Make it global and you should be ok (remove var).

Answer (score 0):

Because the animations are queued but your script keep running, try this one :

```
function changeContent4()
{
    bubble(function(){
        document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML='Some text here';
    });
}
var fadeTimeout = null;
function bubble(callback) {
    if(fadeTimeout==null)
        $("#bubble").fadeIn(1000, function(){
            if($.isFunction(callback))
                callback();
            fadeTimeout = setTimeout(bubbleOff, 20000);
        });
}

function bubbleOff() {
    $("#bubble").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        fadeTimeout =null;
    });
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/Xk7m5/)

You might wanna move the `callback()` call before the fadeIn as you are modifying the text inside the bubble but that exemple is just to let you see the order of every changes

**EDIT** : now allowing multiple call

```
var i = 0;

function changeContent4() {
    bubble(function () {
        $("#text1").text('Some text here ' + (i++));
    });
}

var fadeTimeout = null;

function bubble(callback) {
    if ($.isFunction(callback)) callback();

    if (fadeTimeout == null) {
        $("#bubble").fadeIn(1000, function () {
            fadeTimeout = setTimeout(bubbleOff, 20000);
        });
    } else {
        clearTimeout(fadeTimeout);
        fadeTimeout = setTimeout(bubbleOff, 20000);
    }
}

function bubbleOff() {
    $("#bubble").fadeOut(1000, function () {
        fadeTimeout = null;
    });
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/t2pVL/)

Comment: I would also add that if it's something that need to be done a lot of time inside a same page you should save the element `document.getElementById("text1")` and also use jquery for this as you already have it everywhere

Comment: This works otherwise but now text cannot be changed in another link before timeout goes. I should have mentioned that this is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
function BubbleOn() {
 $("#bubble").fadeIn(function(){},1000)
}
function BubbleOff() {
 $("#bubble").fadeOut(function() {},1000)
}

You should set duration for both fadeIn and fadeOut functions.
```